# Trying to fetch data from Firebase to google sheet

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, fetch

< I'm being tried to get data from firebase database to google sheet with following code but its not working. kindly help me to get the right code >

```js
`function getFacturasClientesExistentes() {
var firebaseUrl = "https://sync-testing-4-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/App%20Data";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
var data = base.getData();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var num = 2;
range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":F"+num+"");
for(var i in data) {
  var values = [
  [ data[i].AppointmentDate, data[i].AppointmentTime, data[i].CallStatus, data[i].ComplaintsStillUnresolved, data[i].CustomerName, data[i].JobType ]
  ];[enter image description here][1]
  range.setValues(values);
  num += 1;
  range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":F"+num+"");
  } 
}
```

`[Firebase Database Child Nodes][1] }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
function getFacturasClientesExistentes() {
  var firebaseUrl = "url here";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 
  var num = 2;
  var keyCount = Object.keys(data).length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, keyCount, 6);
  var values = [];
  for(var i in data) {
     values.push(
        [ data[i].AppointmentDate, data[i].AppointmentTime, data[i].CallStatus, 
          data[i].ComplaintsStillUnresolved, data[i].CustomerName, data[i].JobType]
     )
  }
  range.setValues(values); 
}
```

**Firebase data:**

```
{
  "TEST1" : {
    "AppointmentDate" : "AppointmentDate1",
    "AppointmentTime" : "AppointmentTime1",
    "CallStatus" : "CallStatus1",
    "ComplaintsStillUnresolved" : "ComplaintsStillUnresolved1",
    "CustomerName" : "CustomerName1",
    "JobType" : "JobType1"
  },
  "TEST2" : {
    "AppointmentDate" : "AppointmentDate2",
    "AppointmentTime" : "AppointmentTime2",
    "CallStatus" : "CallStatus2",
    "ComplaintsStillUnresolved" : "ComplaintsStillUnresolved2",
    "CustomerName" : "CustomerName2",
    "JobType" : "JobType2"
  },  
  "TEST3" : {
    "AppointmentDate" : "AppointmentDate3",
    "AppointmentTime" : "AppointmentTime3",
    "CallStatus" : "CallStatus3",
    "ComplaintsStillUnresolved" : "ComplaintsStillUnresolved3",
    "CustomerName" : "CustomerName3",
    "JobType" : "JobType3"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]